# Call Macro by wildcard in cell in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, wildcard

I currently have a combo box in Excel that is assigned to a "Macro List" on a seperate worksheet that has approximately 200 various macros listed. It can be sometimes combersome to search the dropdown to get the macro you want to select (they are in numerical order, so its not too bad) but I think this could be better.

Most of the macros are structured in this way "PA1111_Name" - what I would like is to allow a user to type in just 1111 in a cell and press a "run" button that directs to the above macro. In SQL it would be something like this:

```
SELECT Macro FROM Module WHERE Macro Like '*' & Cell.A2 & '*'
```

These numbers are unique so I'm not concerned with the potential for grabbing multiple macros.

Thank you!

Comment: do you ALWAYS want to call ONLY one macro at a time or there could be some more macros to be called if their names meet criteria?

Comment: a quick way might be to include them all inside one sub and use a case statement to run only the section of code you'd like. Besides that you could use a call by name function if its in a form, or Application.Run if its inside amodule

Comment: @KazJaw yes, there would always only be one macro called at a time in this instance.

Comment: @user2140261 - These macros get edited at times, and I'm afraid of what that would look like with over 200 case statements? I'm trying to keep this list as manageable as possible.

Comment: So you should be able to just use `Application.Run "PA" & [A2] & "_Name"`

Comment: @user2140261 "_Name" was an example, which is why I want to know if I can use a wildcard. It is the name of the contract. Essentially I don't care about what the beginning or the ending is, just that it contains the number in cell A2. that is PA **1111** _Name

Comment: Are all the macros in the same module? If so can you supply the Module name? You will have to do a loop of all Procedures inside your VBProject and do a string compare, then when the match is found execute the Application.Run

Comment: Yes they are all in the same module, the module is named "Mapping"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will go through all macros inside the Mapping Module of the Active VBProject and test to see if the Name contains the Value found in A1, If it does it will run that Macro if none are found it displays No Macro's Found Matching Entered Value.

Remember this will only run the first macro it finds with the Value contained in it, as i assumed you didn't have duplicate values in macro names.

```
Sub RunMacroContainingValue()
Dim cpCurrent As VBComponent
Dim lngCurrentLine As Long
Dim SubName As String
For Each cpCurrent In Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents
    If cpCurrent.Name = "Mapping" Then
        With cpCurrent.CodeModule
            lngCurrentLine = .CountOfDeclarationLines + 1
            Do Until lngCurrentLine >= .CountOfLines
                SubName = .ProcOfLine(lngCurrentLine, 0)
                If InStr(SubName, [A1]) > 0 Then
                    Application.Run SubName
                    Exit Sub
                End If
                lngCurrentLine = .ProcStartLine(SubName, 0) + _
                .ProcCountLines(SubName, 0) + 1
            Loop
        End With
    End If
Next cpCurrent
MsgBox "No Values Found Matching Value"
End Sub
```